# How to store Curry Leaves for many days?

Tags: storage-method

I've used polythene bags and they remain good for at-least 3- 4 days. Then the leaves are becoming dark. How can I store them for at least one/two week(s)?

Answer (score 5):

Put almost all your herbs and leaves in the freezer if you want to keep them for more than 2-3 days. Either in a tight sealed container or ziplock bags. Keep them dry (eg. between layers of kitchen paper as suggested in the comments) so it's easy to separate them when you want to take out some and leave the rest.

Some herbs like cilantro or softer basils will loose their structure when frozen so they are not suitable as raw garnish after freezing (Suggestion in the comments).

Comment: That's a good point. I'm going to try by keeping them dry and then storing in a sealed container. All the time I kept the wet leaves in fridge.

Comment: Additional tip: Put the leaves between layers of kitchen paper, this avoids that they will lump together. Defrost between a fresh sheet of kitchen paper, so any moist gets absorbed immediately.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt "Kitchen paper"? I'm guessing that's a non-American term for something like parchment paper?

Comment: [This stuff](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Kitchen+paper&biw=1829&bih=1031&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMoIPqzIjNAhXMK8AKHRF6CZQQ_AUIBigB) I mean. [Parchment paper](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Kitchen+paper&biw=1829&bih=1031&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMoIPqzIjNAhXMK8AKHRF6CZQQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=parchment+paper) looks like [baking paper](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Kitchen+paper&biw=1829&bih=1031&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMoIPqzIjNAhXMK8AKHRF6CZQQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=Baking+paper) to me :)

Comment: Not all herbs store well in the freezer, but curry leaves do.

Comment: @rackandboneman can you give some examples, please?

Comment: Cilantro or softer basils would certainly be a challenge to home freeze in a way that keeps them usable as a raw garnish..